# Using both PWM and Timer2 interrupt in PIC18F25k50

Tags: pic, pwm, timer

**Background**

I'm working on lead-acid battery charger and experimenting with battery desulfation.

I want to draw current vs time graph on graphic LCD and see:

- how high current spikes I have
- measure RMS of my current if possible

I expect something like this on ADC input:

[image]

**Question**

Can I use Timer2 interrupt when PWM is already using Timer2 in PIC18F25k50?

I want to use that interrupt to "synchronise" my ADC measurements with PWM and catch  current spike.

Answer (score 1):

1. I can see no reason why not. It's quite common to want to synchronize with the PWM, and the interrupt from the timer is most commonly used.
2. That's a little more tricky. You can use the Timer 2 interrupt to trigger a sample, but you want to do a block sample starting at the interrupt time, really, don't you?  Unfortunately it doesn't look like that chip has DMA, so it would really be a case of using T2 to start the sampling, but drive the sampling from another timer / interrupt.

Comment: I realize that will be tricky, but my pulses should be similar. I want to put variable delay in my interrupt and sample many PWM pulses at diffrent phases/points. I think that may work. I mean - I don't have to sample one PWM pulse many times.

Comment: In that case, why do you need to synchronize? Just run your ADC at a slightly different rate to the PWM...?

Comment: I want to have effect similar to trigger in oscilloscope - pulse always in same place on screen.

Comment: If you're sampling repeatedly over the PWM waveform to build up a sample set to represent the waveform, you could use the timer 2's counter to give you the sample number to save, then you just display the sample set from sample 0 to 255 or whatever resolution PWM you're working with.